# Error in jenkins - cannot find the file specified

Tags: jenkins, sh

I have a problem running a job in jenkins. Each time, it cannot find the file that is not there. I don't know if this is a problem with jenkins. Anyway, I didn't add the sh -xe command.

```
 > git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b899772a479187befd2be7382db2a4bc07953ae1 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f b899772a479187befd2be7382db2a4bc07953ae1 # timeout=10
Commit message: "#14502 poprawa"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk b899772a479187befd2be7382db2a4bc07953ae1 # timeout=10
[develop] $ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1627451732551908110.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\develop"): CreateProcess error=2, Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:144)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:92)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1908)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Uruchom powłokę' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you share your pipeline as well as the necessary git repo structure?

Answer (score 1):

Use "Execute Windows batch command" instead of "Execute shell"